# RhinoMocks/AssertWasCalled: verifying argument length?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, arguments, rhino-mocks

My MSpec test will assert that a given method was called with an argument of (at least) a given length.

This syntax is failing the assertion, despite the argument (at runtime) having a length of 534:

```
_foo.AssertWasCalled(x => x.Write(Arg.Text.Like(".{512,}")));
```

> ExpectationViolationException: IFoo.Write(like ".{512,}"); Expected #1, Actual #0.

What have I done wrong with Like()'s pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it is related to the version of RhinoMocks you are using? I'm using RhinoMocks version 3.5.0.1337 and Like detects the length correctly.

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Write(string value);
}

public class Bar
{
    private readonly IFoo _foo;

    public Bar(IFoo foo)
    {
        _foo = foo;
    }
    public void Save(string value)
    {
        _foo.Write(value);
    }
}
```

tests

```
private Bar _bar;
private IFoo _foo;


[SetUp]
public void BeforeEachTest()
{
    var mocker = new RhinoAutoMocker<Bar>();
    _bar = mocker.ClassUnderTest;
    _foo = mocker.Get<IFoo>();
}


[Test]
public void Given_input_length_equal_to_that_required_by_Like()
{
    CallSave("".PadLeft(512));
}

[Test]
public void Given_input_longer_than_required_by_Like()
{
    CallSave("".PadLeft(513));
}

[Test]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ExpectationViolationException))]
public void Given_input_shorter_than_required_by_Like()
{
    CallSave("".PadLeft(511));
}

private void CallSave(string value)
{
    _bar.Save(value);
    _foo.AssertWasCalled(x => x.Write(Arg.Text.Like(".{512,}")));
}
```

The tests also pass if I use .Expect() instead of .AssertWasCalled() by the way.

```
private void CallSave(string value)
{
    _foo.Expect(x => x.Write(Arg.Text.Like(".{512,}")));
    _bar.Save(value);
    _foo.VerifyAllExpectations();
}
```

If these tests pass for you and you are certain about the length of the argument then verify that Write is being called by changing the test to

```
_foo.AssertWasCalled(x => x.Write(Arg<specify type here>.Is.Anything))
```

edit:

The tests also pass with RhinoMocks version 3.6.0.0

Comment: I was using the Like in my assertion instead of my context/setup.  I arranged things per your code, and my code is now working as expected.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not test the length of the arguement directly

```
 Assert.IsTrue(Arg.Text.Length >= 512);
```

Generally in Rhino mocks when you get "Expected #1, Actual #0." it means that there is a problem with Equals, for example not having implemented equals on an object.

Comment: My understanding of Arg.Text is that it's available only during the AssertWasCalled() call?